# Excel 2016 : Right-click --> Refresh in a table does not actually refresh data, from SQL database

Tags: sql-server, excel, refresh, powerquery

According to the official MS website, it states that to [Refresh data from a Microsoft Query, the Data Connection Wizard, or Web query](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/refresh-connected-imported-data-e76a38b0-e2e1-400b-9f2f-c87b9b18c092), I should click `Refresh ALL` from the `Data` tab.

However, if I right-click a table, who's data-source comes from *SQL Server* (PowerQuery - `Source = Sql.Database(`), and click `Refresh`, the data table is simply reloaded from cache.

No actual previous updates in the database are reloaded back to the table. In other words, it doesn't refresh the table at all, but just reloads what it originally had.

Why?

Comment: That is very much not how it normally works. Is this table just the table that was loaded when you first created the query? It's worth noting that when a table in Excel is getting data from Power Query, regardless of the source, it's actually loading an end result of the Query and does not contain a connection to the data source itself. Normally hitting refresh on the table causes Power Query to refresh itself before Excel pulls over the data, but if for some reason that was not happening then I could see getting cached data instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to revert to VBA to do a proper refresh, and it worked. However, this is not a proper solution as it's outside the normal Excel right-click options.

```
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```